# Access PHP data from Array within an Array

Tags: php, arrays, vimeo

Newbie PHP question here:

I am using the Vimeo API to access video information and am using PHP to receive the initial array of data. I know how to access the data by using calls like:

```
echo $array['body']['description'];
```

But I need to access data like this where 'download' would be accessed via

```
echo $array['body']['download'];
```

Specifically where the quality is stated as source as I don't need the other ones. From it I need the link.

```
"download": [
    {
        "quality": "mobile",
        "type": "video/mp4",
        "width": 480,
        "height": 270,
        "expires": "2015-01-07T18:51:48+00:00",
        "link": "LINK",
        "created_time": "2015-01-02T18:47:11+00:00"
    },
    {
        "quality": "source",
        "type": "source",
        "width": 1920,
        "height": 1080,
        "expires": "2015-01-07T18:51:48+00:00",
        "link": "LINK",
        "created_time": "2015-01-02T18:25:19+00:00"
    }
]
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Don't understand the question.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. I am new to PHP and did my best. But there are three great answers below so it is all set!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the array `$array['body']['download']` then check the value of `quality`. If it equals `source` then get the link.

```
foreach( $array['body']['download'] as $innerArray ){
  if( $innerArray['quality'] === 'source' ){
    echo $innerArray['link'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter an array by properties within the array, you can [use `array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with your own filter callable. In your case, try:

```
$downloads = array_filter($array['body']['download'], function($download) {
    return $download['quality'] === 'source';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some like

```
$arr = $array['body']['download'];
$link = '';
for($i = 0; $i <count($arr); $i ++ ){
    if(@$arr[$i]['quality'] == 'source') {
        $link = @arr[$i]['link'];
        break;
    }
}
echo $link;
```